# How do I redirect to another page upon search in React js?

Tags: reactjs

I am currently stuck on a part of my app where if you hit handleSubmit, the goal is to bring you to the product results page. My logic is that I think I have it in the wrong place in the return statement. If anyone can spot the problem that would be awesome! Thank you so much in advance!

```
const Search = () => {
  const [productName, setProductName] = useState('')
  const [result, setResult] = useState([])

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    axios
      .get(`https://topical.herokuapp.com/api/search?name=${productName}`, {
        name: productName
      }).then(result => setResult(result))
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit.then(<Redirect to={`/productlist/${productName}`} />)}>
        <TextField
          label='Enter Product Name:' value={productName}
          onChange={event => setProductName(event.target.value)}
          InputProps={{
            endAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment>
                <IconButton type='submit'>
                  <SearchIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
            )
          }}
        />
      </form>
```

Comment: React is a view binding library, it doesn't have it's own router. You will need to research routers.

Comment: This is why I prefer Angular to React, people say Angular has a larger learning curve than React but that is only because React is a simple view binding library and not a complete framework for developing web applications like Angular. If you are just learning React now maybe look at Angular where you don't have to Frankenstein a bunch of different libraries together to build a full app.

Comment: Are you using the `Redirect` from react-router-dom?

Comment: I will look into Angular when I am done with this, sounds very interesting!

Comment: Yes, Redirect from react-router-dom

Comment: @AdrianBrand thanks for the advice, but advertising about Angular in a react tag seems not really appropriate :D and for the post owner..yeah, you should try Angular first to know why alot of devs are preferring React, and there are some really good concepts you can learn from Angular and implement it in react also.

Comment: I disagree, I am just sharing my experience and personally if someone is beginning their journey on a modern framework I don't see a problem with sharing my opinion on another framework. The comments are exactly where opinions can be stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function **handleSubmit** is not a Promise.

Therefore, it doesn't have a **.then** statement.

What you should be doing is change handleSubmit to **async** function and then **try-catch-finally** the method. After that, **await** the axios since it is a promise.

When the result is not empty, do your redirecting.

This is my most preferred pattern to do asynchronous component level function handlers.

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    try {
        // can put loading of some kind like setLoading(true);
        event.preventDefault();
        const result = await axios
          .get(`https://topical.herokuapp.com/api/search?name=${productName}`, {
            name: productName
          });
        if(!result) {
            return;
            // can throw custom exception here like throw new Error("Searching failed.");
        }
        setResult(result);
        history.push(`/productlist/${productName}`);
    } catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex.message);
    } finally {
         // stop the loader if any setLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

Comment: @SlothsAreGreat  But my question to you is when there is a result coming back from response, what are you trying to do? I don't see any usage on result variable.

Comment: result is the name of the array that returns with the information

Comment: thanks for info, but you are not using it to display data or pass it to next page right..then my above example should work . try this pattern in your project, it will save you alot of time to refactor later.

Comment: I thought it would be like once this is returned then it will go to the next page and then display the information

Comment: then you will have to think about how you can pass that result data to next page. Hint: use a Redux, MobX or some kind of state management library or you can simply just use state to pass the data history.push({
  pathname: `/productlist/${productName}`,
  state: { result: result }
})

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are managing your routes, but in order to your code works, you can change the return method, so, when you have results the page will redirect your  component.

```js
const Search = () => {
  const [productName, setProductName] = useState('')
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null)

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    axios
      .get(`https://topical.herokuapp.com/api/search?name=${productName}`, {
        name: productName
      }).then(result => setResult(result))
  }
  if (result){
    return <Redirect to={`/productlist/${productName}`} />
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmi}>
        <TextField
          label='Enter Product Name:' value={productName}
          onChange={event => setProductName(event.target.value)}
          InputProps={{
            endAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment>
                <IconButton type='submit'>
                  <SearchIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
            )
          }}
        />
      </form>
```

The proper way to do that, is using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) the [Hello Example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation) should solve your issue in a better way.